# Losing angularjs bootstrapping because of ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I'm new to angular and not very familiar with javascript and jade so my questions could sound stupid. My webapp is based on this website: http://www.mircozeiss.com/sync-multiple-angularjs-apps-without-server-via-pouchdb/. It uses pouchdb to build a todo list. I have three different files: services, controllers and index.

services

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.value('version', '0.1');

app.factory('myPouch', [function() {

    var mydb = new PouchDB('ng-pouch');
    PouchDB.replicate('ng-pouch', 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/clients', {continuous: true});
    PouchDB.replicate('http://127.0.0.1:5984/clients', 'ng-pouch', {continuous: true});
    return mydb;

}]);

app.factory('pouchWrapper', ['$q', '$rootScope', 'myPouch', function($q, $rootScope, myPouch) {

    return {
        add: function(text) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var doc = {
                type: 'todo',
                text: text
            };
            myPouch.post(doc, function(err, res) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    if (err) {
                        deferred.reject(err);
                    } else {
                        deferred.resolve(res);
                    }
                });
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        remove: function(id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            myPouch.get(id, function(err, doc) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    if (err) {
                        deferred.reject(err);
                    } else {
                        myPouch.remove(doc, function(err, res) {
                            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                                if (err) {
                                    deferred.reject(err);
                                } else {
                                    deferred.resolve(res);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };

}]);

app.factory('listener', ['$rootScope', 'myPouch', function($rootScope, myPouch) {

    myPouch.changes({
        continuous: true,
        onChange: function(change) {
            if (!change.deleted) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    myPouch.get(change.id, function(err, doc) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                            if (err) console.log(err);
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('newTodo', doc);
                        });
                    });
                });
            } else {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('delTodo', change.id);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

controllers

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', 'listener', 'pouchWrapper', function($scope, listener, pouchWrapper) {

    $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log('submit');
        pouchWrapper.add($scope.text).then(function(res) {
            console.log('test');
            $scope.text = '';
        }, function(reason) {
            console.log(reason);
        });
    };

    $scope.remove = function(id) {
        pouchWrapper.remove(id).then(function(res) {
//      console.log(res);
        }, function(reason) {
            console.log(reason);
        });
    };

    $scope.todos = [];

    $scope.$on('newTodo', function(event, todo) {
        $scope.todos.push(todo);
    });

    $scope.$on('delTodo', function(event, id) {
        for (var i = 0; i<$scope.todos.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.todos[i]._id === id) {
                $scope.todos.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    });

}]);
```

index

```
doctype html
html(ng-app='myApp')
  head
    title=title
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='javascripts/angular-1.2.16.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='javascripts/pouchdb-2.1.0.min.js')

    script(type="application/javascript" src="app/controllers.js")
    script(type="application/javascript" src="app/services.js")
  body

    .container(ng-controller='TodoCtrl')
        h1 TODO application
        p 1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}
            p
                form.form-inline(ng-submit='submit()')
                    input(placeholder='New task', type='text', ng-model='text')
                    input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', value='Add')
            p
                table.table.table-hover.span3
                    thead
                        tr
                            th Task
                            th  
                    tbody
                        tr(ng-repeat='todo in todos')
                            td {{todo.text}}
                            td
                                a.btn.btn-mini.btn-danger(ng-click='remove(todo._id)', href='#') remove
```

In this example, my controller 'TodoCtrl' screws angularjs' bootstrapping (I don't get the result 3). If I remove the container (with the controller), I get the expected result but then I can't use my controller. Anyway, with the container, the submit action doesn't seem to work either.

Any idea? I really want to understand what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks!

Comment: You are creating your module twice (var app = angular.module('myApp', []);). You should remove one of them.

Comment: OK you were right but I'm missing something...in angular's phonecat example, they use different modules' names for each file (services.js controllers.js etc...). Then in the app.js it creates another module such as the other modules from the other files are listed in the table: var app=angular.module('MyApp', ['service.module','controller.module']). I tried to do that (changing my service module to var appSrv = angular.module('service.module', []); and appSrv.factory...) but in my application it doesn't work. FYI I added the app.js in my index. Did I miss something?

Comment: I asked another question about the sub-modules...please answer my question (same as your comment) so I can validate it! Thanks again

Comment: Seems someone answered it :)